# IDE for ECMAScript-262 with in IDE execution / debugging for node.js/V8

Tags: javascript, ide, node.js, v8, ecma262

I currently use Eclipse as my IDE for other languages and I'm rather used to not having to leave the IDE for anything - however I'm really struggling to find the same or a similar setup for pure ECMAScript-262.

To clarify, I am not looking for DOM support, jquery, HTML or anything like that, preferably just an IDE with ECMAScript-262 support (pref node.js) built in (debugging not important) so that I can simply run my code in the IDE.

Any ideas?

ps: please don't suggest aptana.

Comment: Since you like Eclipse, I'm surprised you don't want Aptana. What is the reason?

Comment: re Aptana, I've had lots of problems previously with it - however for this the main reason is because it uses a browser based debugger (firefox) and I'm looking for non dom, non browser V8 based debugging (more of a binary/cli integration)

Comment: WebStorm from www.jetbrains.com is excellent for JavaScript, because it supports ECMAScript 5, understands JsDoc perfectly (inheritance and all). It's the only IDE that actually does that.

Answer (score 1):

[jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/index.php) is about what you want. Take a look at the plugins available.

So far, it seems there has only been [talk](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/14288d427986b920) about integrating node.js debugging with Google Chrome. But that may be exactly your answer if it happens.

Comment: yup already had that node/chrome setup.. see: http://wiki.github.com/ry/node/using-eclipse-as-node-applications-debugger - as for JEdit, thanks will check it out in a moment!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind to pay a price, I advice [Jetbrains WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/).

Recently purchased a license myself (it's not that expensive) and am very happy with it.
Before I used Eclipse and Aptana, but seriously, WebStorm IS quality.

Not sure if I am currently breaking a rule by linking to a commercial product, but it IS an awnser ;)

Comment: When I was doing Java development, I used Jetbrains IntelliJ IDEA, and it was the best Java IDE I'd ever used, especially with its support for refactoring things - with the web, you can refactor JavaScript, HTML; it has nice shortcut keys for wrapping things and selecting things. Definitely a worthwhile experience, and probably worth the cost. There's also an Open Source version. Not sure if the Open Source version is as good or not, might also be an alternative.

Comment: Open source IDEA does not contain the javascript refactoring tools. Just syntax highlighting.

Comment: Only have to pay the price when you want the upgrades ;) Still using Webstorm 2.0 and it's still fine for my purposes ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is [Nodeclipse effort](http://www.nodeclipse.org/).

> Vision
>
> One-stop shop for Node.js tools. We can't develop everything at once,
>   but we let you know what are the best things around for Node.js
>   development with Eclipse.

Latest version is 0.4, works well in Eclipse 4.3 Kepler.

It has integrated ChromeDevTools and V8 remote debugger for debugging Node.js application,
that is quite useful when learning Node.js to understand what is happening in memory.
Also comes with markdown (.md) Editor (The same markup language that is used on GitHub, Stackoverflow.com & npm)

It is free [open-source hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/Nodeclipse)